# Jaxb marshal null field to empty attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm looking for a way to force jaxb to marshal null attributes as empty string

If I consider a class with to attributes, the current behaviour is:

```
att1 = "toto"
att2 = "titi"
```

this is marshalled as:

```
<element att1="toto" att2="titi"> 
</element>
```

So far so good, but when on attribute is empty i got:
    att1 = "toto"
    att2 = null

this is marshalled as:

```
<element att1="toto"> 
</element>
```

I'd like it to be marshalled as:

```
<element att1="toto" att2=""> 
</element>
```

So far all i could found was about XmlElement when my concern is about XmlAttribute. Does anyone have any idea about a way to force an empty String ?

I can't do a pre-modification of my objects to put an empty String instead of the null value when needed, since some of the attributes involves in my issue are Date and Long.